# Can I install Minecraft: Pocket Edition on multiple devices?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have purchased this app on my iPad and want my kids to be able to play it on their iPad.  Can I load it on their iPad without having to purchase it again?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. As long as that device is configured with the same Apple ID that you purchased the app with, you can download your iOS apps on as many devices as you'd like.

If you're planning to do so, I would also recommend [setting up parental controls](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213) to ensure that your kids can't make any unauthorized purchases.

Comment: I would not recommend this to the OP, seeing that she asked this question to start with. She would run into issues like her kids buying stuff off microtransactions without her knowing.

Comment: @deutschZuid There are parental controls to take care of that. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213

Comment: I am aware of the solutions; I was just saying that if she has to ask this question, then she might not be aware of those other issues, let alone the solutions. I don't have any problem with your solution at all; it's perfect for the context. I just fear she doesn't know what she could get herself into by using her own account on multiple devices used by her kids.

Comment: @deutschZuid That's a valid concern, but I feel like that's sort of outside the scope of what we're here for. Regardless, I edited in a recommendation for that. Thanks for the tip!